Is $e^x \cos(e^x) f(x)$ absolutely integrable on $\mathbb{R}$ for any Schwartz function $f$?
In this ME post, it is said that the function $e^x \cos(e^x)$ is a tempered distribution on $\mathbb{R}$. Namely, we have
\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^x \cos(e^x) f(x) dx = -\int_{\mathbb{R}} \sin (e^x)f'(x) dx
\end{equation}
for any Schwartz function $f$.
However, I am uncertain about Lebesgue integrability of $e^x \cos(e^x) f(x)$.

That is, do we have $\int_{\mathbb{R}} \bigl \lvert e^x \cos(e^x) f(x) \bigr \rvert dx <\infty$ for any Schwartz function $f$?

I am not convinced about this due to the exponential term $e^x$ in the integrand. If I turn out to be right, it is not clear to me how we make sense of the integral $\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^x \cos(e^x) f(x) dx $ $\textit{itself}$.
Is this integral just "defined" by the right-hand side of the above equality?
Could anyone please clarify for me?

I think your equation is not quite correct. Probably you want to have a derivative on the RHS and an $e^x$ (instead of $x$) as an argument on the LHS.

No it is not absolutely integrable. Just consider a smooth function $f$ which is say $0$ for $x<0$ and becomes positive in the middle and then for $x\in (1,\infty)$ it becomes $e^{-x}$. Then, $f$ is a Schwartz function (when $x>1$ we have $f(x)=e^{-x}$ so we have exponential decay so it definitely decays faster than any polynomial). However, for $x>1$, we have $e^x\cos(x)f(x)=\cos x$ which is not absolutely integrable on $(1,\infty)$. Having said that, it seems to me you have a typo?

@SeverinSchraven You are absolutely right..Thank you for pointing out the typo.

@peek-a-boo Yes, I just fixed the typo as pointed out by the first comment. Now, is $e^x \cos(e^x) f(x)$ still not absolutely integrable?

my same counterexample still works since $\int_R^{\infty}\left|\frac{\cos y}{y}\right|,dy=\infty$ for every $R>0$.

@Keith I think you are still missing a derivative on the RHS.

@peek-a-boo Thank you. Then, in what precise sense do we have to understand LHS of the equality above? Perhaps by limit of integrals on $[-N,N]$ as $N \to \infty$?

@SeverinSchraven I am dumb...thank you.

I think the point is that the map
$$ T: C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \varphi \mapsto \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^x \cos(e^x) \varphi(x) dx $$
is well-defined and defines a distribution. For $\varphi\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ we can integrate by parts and get
$$ T(\varphi) = -\int_{\mathbb{R}} \sin(e^x) \varphi'(x) dx. $$
Now this later formulation can be easily seen to also define a tempered distribution. Saying that $e^x \cos(e^x)$ yields a tempered distribution seems a bit sloppy to me (as the naive integration against Schwartz functions is ill-defined as the example of peek-a-boo shows).
Added: Let me comment on the existence of the extension. It needs to be unique (as $C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ is dense in $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$, see Show smooth functions of compact support are dense in the Schwartz space). The RHS (with the derivative) is easily seen to be continuous with respect to the topology on the Schwartz space, as we have $$ \left\vert \int_{\mathbb{R}} \sin(e^x) \varphi'(x) dx \right\vert \leq \int_{\mathbb{R}} \vert \varphi'(x) \vert dx \leq \left(\sup_{y\in \mathbb{R}} \vert (1+y^2) \varphi'(y) \vert \right)\int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{1}{1+x^2} dx. $$

Yes. What I am confused about is to make sense of the integral in your first formula for $T$. I don't think it is rigorous to just say "integrate by parts" in the first formula for $T$, since the integrand is not absolutely integrable in general.

@Keith It is rigorous to integrate by parts because $\varphi$ has compact support.

@Keith That is why I defined $T$ first for $C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ exactly because I do not need $e^x \cos(e^x)$ to be integrable, it is enough if it is differentiable (that is because for functions in $C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ we are really only integrating over a bounded interval and all differentiable functions will be integrable). Does that clear things up?

Oh I didn't look at your domain correctly....In this case, we should show that $T$ can be (uniquely) extended to a tempered distribution. However, this part seems nontrivial.

@Keith It is not that hard. I have added some details.

Thank you. After all, it seems that the equality in my post above is more like a "definition", in accordance with the second-to-last sentence in the post.
